# WSO2 Identity Server 4.5 wrongly redirect to localhost when doing sso

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server

I've developed a sso filter and it worked fine with identity server4.1
However, when I migrate to 4.5, it keeps redirecting to localhost:9443 instead of the url i configured.(My Identity server is on another server)

So is it a bug or do i need do some extra configuration on identity server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to do one more config. Locate the application-authenticators.xml file in the path wso2is-4.5.0/repository/conf/security/application-authenticators.xml. Locate the bellow config

```
loginPage="https://localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint/login.do"
```

There change the hostname accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for replying. But the problem has 2 halves: first one, it will redirect to https://localhost:9443/commonauth ,  then if i change 'localhost' to my host name, it will again redirect to https://localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint/login.do .After applying 'loginPage' configuration above, it solves 2nd half of the problem, but it still redirects to https://localhost:9443/commonauth

Comment: Yes, it will redirects to the commonauth for authentication. That is where now authentication is happening.

Comment: but why localhost? I cannot find any places to figure the url for commonauth.

Comment: can you make sure if you have configured the hostname correctly in the carbon.xml file ?

Comment: OK, I solved the problem by configuring 'MgtHostname'. Changing 'HostName' alone doesn't help.  However, I think sso url shouldn't be affected by MgtHostName, since it's a management console.

Comment: @CrazyInDark I followed your instructions and it seems with the change of the host in the carbon.xml it getting a little further. Nonetheless it ends in http://x.x.x.x/authenticationendpoint/login.donull. Did you see that error before?

Answer (score 0):

You means that from your filter, it is always redirecting to localhost:9443 (SAML Auth request)? Or else after authenticating (after entering user name and passwords) with Identity Server, it redirected to localhost:9443?

Comment: Before authentication. see my reply to Suresh.